# How to use environment variables defined in the Codebuild console, within the buildspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-codebuild

Environment variables declared within the Codebuild console, are not getting resolved.

I've tried as many variations of variable usage with YAML as I could think of;

```
$VARIABLE
${VARIABLE}
"$VARIABLE"
```

version: 0.2

```
env:
  variables:
    AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME: "AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME"
    API_URL: "API_URL"
  parameter_store:
   aws_access_key: "my-access-key"
   aws_secret_key: "my-secret-key"

phases:
 install:
  runtime-versions:
   python: 3.7
 post_build:
  commands: >-
    AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
    SOURCE_REPO_URL=${CODEBUILD_SOURCE_REPO_URL}
    SOURCE_BRANCH=${CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION}
    AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME=${AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME}
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY=${aws_access_key}
    AWS_SECRET_KEY=${aws_secret_key}
    // custom script
```

The docs specify you need to have this env structure of key/value pairs. Where key is the name I want to use, and value is the name of the variable/parameter to get the value from.

When running in Codebuild, the output simply shows exactly what's written, rather than replacing the variables...

Answer (score 1):

Just remove block chomping indicator, **>-**, after *"commands:"*. That just prevents variable substitution.

You can use either $VARIABLE or ${VARIABLE} in your buildspec.

Answer (score 0):

try using echo first to see you can see the value. I used as follows it worked for me

```
    version: 0.2
env:
 variables:
     key: "value"
pre_build:
   commands:
     - echo ${key}
```